# Current User isn't nil after calling PFUser.logOut() parse, swift2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, pfuser

I want to build a simple LogOut Button with parse but the current user is not getting nil.

```
PFUser.logOut()
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() // this should be nil but it isn't :(
print(currentUser)
```

I also tried:

```
PFUser.logOutInBackground()
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() // this is also not nil :(
```

So when I print the currentUser it is not nil like it should be. It is:

```
Optional(<PFUser: 0x7f8d99dd2320 , objectId: new, localId: local_58d62becf7a6f1dc> {
```

})

So I think the app is creating a new user?!

Answer (score 5):

Try commenting out the following line of code in your AppDelegate.swift file -

```
PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
```

enableAutomaticUser() will log in an anonymous user once you call PFUser.logOut(), and the username for an anonymous user is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if we have a currentUser in the AppDelegate in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
   let user = PFUser.currentUser()
      if user == nil
       {
           // present loginViewController
       }
      else
        {
           print("user is \(user?.username)")  // <--- who is currently 
          // show any viewcontroller 
        }
```

Your logout Button should send the user back to the loginViewController after Login out of your app.
  Example:

```
        @IBAction func Logout(sender:UIButton)
         {
            PFUser.Logout()
            let LoginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyBoardID") 
            self.presentViewController(LoginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
```

So From the Login View Controller, they could use their credentials to sign in back into your app, **then the currentUser won't return a nil**

Comment: But I want it to be nil, because if i implement your code and the user quits the app before loggin in again, the current user isn't nil so he is logged in again

Comment: so thats why you make sure in the app delegate to see if the currentUser is null or not.. if null present the Login, if not show the any view controller

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the PfUser.currentUser() is not ever getting nil

Comment: just follow me for a second, `check the edit code`, so when you pressed the Logout button it will sign out the  user, then present the login view, from the login view the user sign in and now close the app because of the code that checks if we have a user in the delegate because we didn't pressed the logout button we will go to the application directly

Comment: I have already done all of the stuff you are explaining but the only problem I have is that PFUser.currentUser() is not getting NIL there is always something in it! .I updated my question.

Comment: Maybe you should reset the simulator

Answer (score 0):

Set *return type* of the function(logout) as *optional type*. Only *optionals* has the capability of holding nil value.
Here is the example that i want to tell you

```
func loggedOut() -> Int? {

    // check you conditions here ex:
  if score > 0 {
  return score 
  } else {
 return nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Here, my intension is to tell you above edited code , have a look at that